# One TCP socket for sending and receiving packets

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

Good afternoon.
The task is to write one program that will run on two machines on different networks. This program should establish a TCP connection with the same program on another network and they should exchange packets.
This is the first time I have encountered such a task, so some difficulties arose.

In the classic client / server architecture, there is a socket for receiving messages and a socket for sending messages. Since my program, in fact, combines a client and a server, the question is - is it possible to implement both receiving and sending on the same TCP socket?

The logic is as follows - we create a tcp socket (in sockaddr_in we fill in the Ip and port of our local machine), we do bind, then we do listen. Then we make connect (in sockaddr_in, fill in the Ip and port of the second machine with whom we want to connect) and accept.
It turns out connect, we send a request to the listen queue on the second machine, and then, through accept, we pull this request out of the queue and get a socket descriptor, through which we are already sending and receiving messages.

Will this logic work, or do you need to do something differently?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't understand your question well, but it is possible to send and receive via one TCP socket. This feature is used in many application-level protocols like HTTP, FTP, SMTP, etc.

Comment: Are you allowed to have a flag to specify if the program is to run as the server or as the client?

Comment: you should accept a command line parameter that makes it either a server or a client, then it's just a matter of implementing 2 different functions/classes - each for server and client.

Comment: This "In the classic client / server architecture, there is a socket for receiving messages and a socket for sending messages" is simply not correct.

Comment: In the classic client/server architecture, the client connects to a listening server and they send and receive data **over the same socket**, not different sockets.

Answer (score 2):

As Abhinav says, you should use the command line to specify the behaviour you want the program to have.  A good way to do that would be:

```
$ my_program :28728      # try to listen as a server on port 28728
$ my_program hostname:28728    # try to connect as a client
```

You can find the command line argument from `int main(int argc, const char* argv[])` -> `if (argc == 2)` then `argv[1]` will have some text, and you can see if the first character is a ':' to know which mode to run the program in.

For the TCP server mode, create a `socket`, `bind`, `listen` and `accept` a client connection.
For the TCP client mode, create a `socket` and `connect` to the server.

Once connected, the TCP connection is a peer-to-peer connection with both sides equally empowered to send and receive data using `send()` and `recv()`.

Whenever I want to write this kind of code, I turn to the GCC libc examples: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Stream-Example.html to remind me of all the steps.